# Error creating relationship in SQL/PHP after submission

Tags: php, mysql

I have a registration form where companies register their business along with 5 locations they operate in. The companies and locations data are stored in separate tables and are then associated with each other with a 3rd relations table.

Here is my code but I'm unsure how to populate the relations table successfully.

For instance say the user submitted croydon which has an id of 3, then the relationship table should look like the one below which I filled in manually but I cannot find a way to populate it automatically!

Here are how my tables look;

**Companies**

[image: Companies]

**Locations**

[image: Locations]

**Relationship Table** (This is a manual entry as an example)

[image: Relationship Table]

```
// IMPORT TO DATABASE
$query = "INSERT INTO partners (partner_id, partner_name, email_address, contact_number, active, street_number, street_name, town_city, postcode, country)

VALUES

(NULL, '".$companyname."', '".$email."', '".$contactnumber."', 'yes', '".$street_number."', '".$street_name."', '".$town_city."', '".$postcode."', '".$country."')";

$connect->query($query);

//INSERT NEW LOCATIONS TO DATABASE

$insert = "INSERT IGNORE INTO locations (location_id, location_name) VALUES (NULL, '".$area1."')";
$insert .= ", (NULL, '".$area2."')";
$insert .= ", (NULL, '".$area3."')";
$insert .= ", (NULL, '".$area4."')";
$insert .= ", (NULL, '".$area5."')";
$insert .= ";";                                                 

if ($connect->query($insert) === TRUE) {

} else {

echo "Error: " . $insert . "<br>" . $connect->error;
}

//RELATE PARTNER TO LOCATIONS
```

*** SOLVED ***

```
// GET LOCATION ID 1
                                                        $get_location_id_one = "SELECT location_id FROM locations WHERE (location_name = '$area1')";

                                                        if ($location_ids = $connect->query($get_location_id_one)) {
                                                            foreach ($location_ids as $location_id) {
                                                                $location_id1 = $location_id['location_id'];
                                                            }
                                                        } else {
                                                            echo "Error: No Locations<br>";
                                                        }
                                                        // GET LOCATION ID 2
                                                        $get_location_id_one = "SELECT location_id FROM locations WHERE (location_name = '$area2')";

                                                        if ($location_ids = $connect->query($get_location_id_one)) {
                                                            foreach ($location_ids as $location_id) {
                                                                $location_id2 = $location_id['location_id'];
                                                            }
                                                        } else {
                                                            echo "Error: No Locations<br>";
                                                        }
                                                        // GET LOCATION ID 3
                                                        $get_location_id_one = "SELECT location_id FROM locations WHERE (location_name = '$area3')";

                                                        if ($location_ids = $connect->query($get_location_id_one)) {
                                                            foreach ($location_ids as $location_id) {
                                                                $location_id3 = $location_id['location_id'];
                                                            }
                                                        } else {
                                                            echo "Error: No Locations<br>";
                                                        }
                                                        // GET LOCATION ID 4
                                                        $get_location_id_one = "SELECT location_id FROM locations WHERE (location_name = '$area4')";

                                                        if ($location_ids = $connect->query($get_location_id_one)) {
                                                            foreach ($location_ids as $location_id) {
                                                                $location_id4 = $location_id['location_id'];
                                                            }
                                                        } else {
                                                            echo "Error: No Locations<br>";
                                                        }
                                                        // GET LOCATION ID 5
                                                        $get_location_id_one = "SELECT location_id FROM locations WHERE (location_name = '$area5')";

                                                        if ($location_ids = $connect->query($get_location_id_one)) {
                                                            foreach ($location_ids as $location_id) {
                                                                $location_id5 = $location_id['location_id'];
                                                            }
                                                        } else {
                                                            echo "Error: No Locations<br>";
                                                        }

                                                        $insert = "INSERT INTO partners_locations (partners_locations_id, partner_id, location_id) VALUES (NULL, '".$partner_id."', '".$location_id1."')";
                                                        $insert .= ", (NULL, '".$partner_id."', '".$location_id2."')";
                                                        $insert .= ", (NULL, '".$partner_id."', '".$location_id3."')";
                                                        $insert .= ", (NULL, '".$partner_id."', '".$location_id4."')";
                                                        $insert .= ", (NULL, '".$partner_id."', '".$location_id5."')";
                                                        $insert .= ";"; 


                                                        $connect->query($insert);
```

Comment: After doing an insert, you can obtain the generated id by executing the function mysql_insert_id ().
Save the inserted partner in a variable called $partner_id. Then split your location query in 5 separated insert queries and save the inserted locations ids.
Finally, execute 5 queries with the partner_id and the five location_id.

Comment: Cheers for the pablo, I'm still learning so I will give this a go! any hint on how the code should look?

Comment: also some locations may already be inserted do I still get an id if its skipped?

Comment: No, it will return a 0 instead. But knowing this, you can then do a SELECT to get the ID.

Comment: I would caution against insert ignore. I would not give NULL as first param (just skip it) for auto_inc pk columns. I would consider `insert on duplicate key update`. But the devil's in the details. And, as spencer said, sql injection. With the insert, susceptible to 2nd order attacks (little timebombs that can go off later)

Answer (score 0):

To get a row inserted to the "relationship" table, you need the value assigned to `partner_id` column from the row that was inserted into the `partners` (Companies?) table.

If that column is an AUTO_INCREMENT column... you can retrieve the value that was assigned using the MySQL `LAST_INSERT_ID` function.

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Immediately following a successful insert, you can run a query `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()`. Most database extensions expose this same functionality, so you don't have to muck up your code with an extra SQL statement. The database extension will handle running the SELECT and returning you the value.

For example:

[**mysqli_insert_id**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)

[**PDO lastInsertId**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)

You can make use of that retrieved value in an INSERT into the "relationship" table.

---

I strongly recommend you make use of **prepared statements** with **bind placeholders**.  The code you have posted appears to be vulnerable to SQL Injection (incorporating potentially unsafe values into the SQL text.)

If you don't use bind placeholders, at a minimum, the values should be run through an escape function...

For example, [**mysqli_real_escape_string**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Reference: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection